# PrimeNg/Treeselect - How to select node programmatically

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

`

```
<p-treeSelect
          selectionMode="checkbox"
          [options]="nodes"
          (onNodeSelect)="onSelectedChange($event)"
          placeholder="Select"
></p-treeSelect>
```

`

The checkbox should be selected already, how to achieve this using p-treeselect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` to bind your data and then its automatically selected.

Customised with official tree example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselect-demo-fayhbl

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with the TreeSelect component in PrimeNG, and after some investigation, I managed to find a solution..

Here's the link to my answer on GitHub: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3285#issuecomment-1582368388

In the answer, I explain the problem I faced and provide step-by-step instructions on how to overcome it. The solution involves referencing the TreeSelect component using the @ViewChild decorator and using the onShow event to select nodes programmatically.

I hope my answer on GitHub helps you in resolving your issue as well. Feel free to check it out and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Could you please include a brief summary of your solution here?